# Multiple 1 to 1 relationships for common model

Tags: orm, laravel-4, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship, eloquent

I'm building an app with Laravel 4 and using Eloquent as the ORM.

I think the easiest way to describe my question is with an example, albeit an unlikely one...

I have a Cookie model (as in OREO etc). Cookie can in turn belong to a Human or an Alien. So...

Is it possible (correct) to say:

A Cookie belongs to Human

AND

A Cookie belongs to Alien?

The same Cookie can't belong to both a Human and and Alien or shared between members of the same species.

So I guess what I'm really asking is, can the Cookie table have two foreign key columns, one for Humans and one for Aliens?

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have this:

```
name       type   nullable
------------------------------
id         int    no
name       text   no
human_id   int    yes 
alien_id   int    yes
```

Those could be your classes:

```
class Cookie extends Eloquent {

    public function human()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Human', 'human_id');
    }

    public function alien()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Alien', 'alien_id');
    }

}

class Alien extends Eloquent {

    public function cookie()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Cookie', 'alien_id');
    }

}

class Human extends Eloquent {

    public function cookie()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Cookie', 'human_id');
    }

}
```

And then you could use them this way:

```
$human = Human::find(1);

echo $human->cookie->name;

$cookie = Cookie::find(1);

if ($cookie->human) echo $cookie->human->name;
if ($cookie->alien) echo $cookie->alien->name;
```

Comment: Looks exactly like what I had in mind. It's always good to get confirmation as to whether something is a good idea or 'good practice'. Thank you for your detailed response.

Comment: Antonio, just a quick question. I can open a separate question if the answer is not straight forward. How would I handle a model, instances of which can occur as children of each other. For example, a Section in a text book, could have many sub sections, which can themselves have sub sections etc etc. Foreign key inside the Section table referring to itself?

Comment: Nested sets are a problem on any language. I'm handling them using recursive SQL queries, but you can use a package like this one: http://registry.autopergamene.eu/package/etrepat-baum.